# consulta multitablas desde Java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, netbeans-8.2

estoy utilizando una base de datos con 6 tablas en mysql y debo hacer una consulta desde java a esas 6 tablas de acuerdo al Id que va como parámetro.. cuando ejecuto la consulta en la misma BD me ejecuta sin ningún problema. En la consulta utilizo el JOIN y me gustaría que me digan cual es la forma correcta de almmacenar esos datos, trabajo con la estructura MVC, con jsp y servlet

```
public class ReporteDao {


    public  Reporte lista(int id){
    Reporte rep=new Reporte();
    try {
        String SQL = "select T.nombTipo, S.nombUsuario, S.direccion, S.codCatastral, A.idActividad, 
         A.actividad, A.unidMedida, D.cantidad, A.costo, D.costoInst, I.utilidad, I.subtotal, I.igv, 
       I.total, U.nombUsuario, I.fecha
       from actividad A
       join detinstalacion D on A.idActividad=D.idActividad
       join instalacion I on I.idInstalacion=D.idInstalacion
       join tipoinstalacion T on T.idTipo=I.idTipo
       join uservicio S on S.idUsuario=I.idUsuario
       join usuario U on U.idUsuario=I.idUsSist
       where I.idInstalacion="+id;
        Connection con = Conexion.conectar();
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        ResultSet result =st.executeQuery();
        while(result.next()){

            rep.setNombTipo(result.getString("nombTipo"));
            rep.setNombUsuario(result.getString("nombUsuario"));
            rep.setDireccion(result.getString("direccion"));
            rep.setCodCatastral(result.getString("codCatastral"));
            rep.setIdActividad(result.getInt("idActividad"));
            rep.setActividad(result.getString("actividad"));
            rep.setUnidMedida(result.getString("unidMedida"));
            rep.setCantidad(result.getDouble("cantidad"));
            rep.setCosto(result.getDouble("costo"));
            rep.setCostoInst(result.getDouble("costoInst"));
            rep.setUtilidad(result.getDouble("utilidad"));
            rep.setSubtotal(result.getDouble("subtotal"));
            rep.setIgv(result.getDouble("igv"));
            rep.setTotal(result.getDouble("total"));
            rep.setNombUsuarioSist(result.getString("nombUsuario"));
            rep.setFecha(result.getDate("fecha"));
            //cual seria la forma correcta de obtener los datos?

        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {


    }

  return rep;
}
 //en el controlador trato de obtener de esta forma pero no me obtiene nada
  Reporte repor=new Reporte();
      ReporteDao rdao=new ReporteDao();
        repor=rdao.list(105);
        String nombtipo=repor.getNombTipo();
        request.setAttribute("pp", nombtipo);

     // en el jsp
     <input type="text" name="txtcon"  value="${pp}">
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer, qué errores o dificultades tienes y en qué parte del código?

Comment: agrega los errores para ver que esta sucediendo

Comment: el problema es cuando trato de obtener eses valores en el controlador no me obtiene